# Animated tabs with first content active

Tags: html, css

I have this animated tabs written in CSS code and i'm trying to set the first content visible (active) when loading the homepage, not needing to click on it to read it.. This can work with javascript?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,500,700,900);

*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

body{
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #6e6e6e;
  box-shadow: 0rem 0.1rem  #2c2c2c;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 4rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

nav a::last-of-type{
  border: 0;
}

nav ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

main{
  position: relative;
  top: 4rem;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 5%;
  top: 0;
  
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
}

.container:not(:target){
  margin-top: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:target{
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#no1-container">No1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#no2-container">No2</a></li>
  </ul> 
</nav>  

<main>
  <section id="no1-container" class="container"> 
    <h1>No1</h1> 
    
    <p>This is first content</p>  
  </section> 
  
  <section id="no2-container" class="container">
    <h1>No2</h1> 
    
    <p>This is second content</p> 
  </section> 
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#no1-container" id="no1-container">No1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#no2-container">No2</a></li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

Add this jQuery code to your project.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#no1-container").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to add this JavaScript code to you html page.

window.onload = function() {

    this.location = this.location + "#no1-container";
};